# Prevent anonymous users from accessing "node/" node/%nid and taxonomy/term/%tid

Tags: users, panels

So far, I have been reading some similar questions but I haven't found an elegant and simple way of doing this (if there is any). As I say in the question title, I don't want anonymous users to access the complete list of nodes (in node/) nor a particular node (under node/%nid), nor even a particular taxonomy term. :)

My approach to this is as follows. As far as I know, I can override the default node/%nid system page using a variant in Drupal panels. I actually did this and, if the user is not logged in, when he/she tries to access the node/%nid he/she will see a log in box. For the list of nodes, I removed from the front page all of the nodes and none is shown. I would expect to do with taxonomy/term/%tid the same as I did with node/%nid but, for a strange reason, Drupal panels is not able to create the variant (not sure if it is a bug).

Anyway, I would like to know if you have a more elegant or simpler approach to this (no matter if using panels or not).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I've hacked the Securesite module to only protect certain paths. You might also be able to use the Redirect module to redirect users who don't have the right roles to a different page if they try to view those.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in the template.php? what if you do something like:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook){
   if(!$user->uid){
      if((arg(0) == 'node') || (arg(0) == 'taxonomy')){
         //redirect to login
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The theme layer isn't the best place for access control.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Panels, it can be done that way by using the default pages:

- node_view
- term_view

The trick with term_view is to enable the default taxonomy_term View, give it a *different path*, e.g 'view/taxonomy/term/%' and embed that in the term_view Panel.

Lastly, make sure you add a catch all "HTTP Response Code: 403" variant to your Panel page to catch those that don't have access to view the content.

Another option is

- [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)

and added your own access callback to the node view and taxonomy term view menu items.

For example, to disable access to '/node'

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter
 */
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['node']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

Lastly with node view it's also possible to use the comprehensive

- [Node Access API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/group/node_access/7).

Comment: I will take a look at this way David, and see what happens. Thanks for taking time to reply.

Comment: 'Lastly, make sure you add a catch all "HTTP Response Code: 403" variant to your Panel page to catch those that don't have access to view the content.' I can't find a way of doing this with panels. Can you give me some orientation please?